# Problemas com o CSS

Tags: css

sou novo aqui e estou programando em CSS,me problema é o seguinte:
Eu consigo fazer e colocar os códigos normalmente no sublime text, mas na hora de ver o resultado no navegador ele não aparece. O que eu faço ?

Comment: está importando ele corretamente no seu HTML?

Comment: E o codigo pode postar?

Comment: tem a certeza que está a importar o ficheiro de css correto: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CAMINHO PARA O FICHEIRO AQUI">`?

Comment: Sim Miguel, já importe o ficheiro, mas msm assim não apareceu... Vou tentar fazer aqui denovo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a estrutura abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Título da página</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CAMINHO_PARA_ARQUIVO.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Ela funciona perfeitamente! Todas as minhas páginas na web são construidas com esse modelo e nunca tive nenhum tipo de problema. Só linkar de forma CORRETA o css e pronto, tudo funcionando! :D

Tente observar no console de desenvolvedor, se estiver utilizando o Google Chrome, se ele não está dando problema de Cross Origin! Geralmente o chrome bloqueia requisições externas para a mesma página seguindo essa política de mesma origem. Se estiver com esse problema, tente rodar a página em um servidor local (como: xampp, wamp, lamp, etc) e veja se corrige o problema!

Comment: Vlw Lucas, funcionou aqui! "+1"